# How can I open, edit and save an MS-Word document programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ms-word

I want to make a word editor for IOS in which I can open MS-Word documents and edit them like in MS Office and after that I can save the document. Can anyone help? I couldn't find any helping code. I tried to find the SDK forms-office but that is not available. I have tried google sdk for text documents which is DrEdit https://github.com/googledrive/dredit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Office can read and write MS-Word Documents, and their code is open. Probably hard to find the right passages, but better that reverse engineering the format yourself.

The code is here:
http://openoffice.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Fallen please help me where is the code for open/edit a word document in this above link

Answer (score -1):

You can try with ThatPDF . Its basically for annotation of PDF but you can customise it for word documents. [Here](https://github.com/Ink/ThatPDF) is the Github link for the open source project.